# transfer file from local WSL ubuntu to remote server

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, scp, windows-subsystem-for-linux, file-transfer

I have a file called `test1.zip` in `/mnt/c/Users/test/` folder of my local laptop [in which ubuntu windows subsystem for linux is installed]. Local ubuntu terminal WSL name is `lauda`

Now, I would like to transfer this zip file called `test1.zip` to my remote server named `stuff`.

**PLEASE NOTE THAT ALL COMMANDS ARE TRIED FROM MY LOCAL LAPTOP WSL SCREEN [ubuntu screen]**

So, I tried the below command from my WSL [local laptop ubuntu WSL terminal]

```
scp user1@lauda:/mnt/c/Users/test/test1.zip user1@stuff:/home/test/codes/test1
```

and got the error `ssh: Could not resolve hostname lauda: Name or service not known`

So I tried the below [replacing the `lauda` local laptop ubuntu terminal hostname with its IP]

```
scp user1@172.xx.xxx.xxx:/mnt/c/Users/test/test1.zip user1@stuff:/home/test/codes/test1
```

this resulted in error as `ssh: connect to host 172.xx.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection refused`

Now I tried the same command as above but in opposite way as shown below

```
scp user1@stuff:/home/test/codes/ user1@lauda:/mnt/c/Users/test/test1.zip
```

and got the below error

`ssh: Could not resolve hostname lauda: Temporary failure in name resolution`

Later, I tried with IP address

```
 scp user1@stuff:/home/test/codes/ user1@172.xx.xxx.xxx:/mnt/c/Users/test/test1.zip
```

And I got the below error

`ssh: connect to host 172.xx.xxx.xxx port 22: No route to host lost connection`

Later, I tried the below commands as well

```
scp /mnt/c/Users/test/test1.zip user1@stuff:/home/test/codes/
```

and got an error `scp: /home/test/codes/test1.zip: Permission denied`

So, I again tried like below

```
scp user1@stuff:/home/test/codes/ /mnt/c/Users/test/test1.zip
```

and got an error `scp: /home/test/codes: not a regular file`

**PLEASE NOTE THAT ALL COMMANDS ARE TRIED FROM MY LOCAL LAPTOP WSL SCREEN [ubuntu screen]**

How can I transfer local files/folders from my local ubuntu WSL terminal to remote server?

Answer (score 2):

I would check your permissions on the .zip file. You need at least read access to transfer the file. I would also confirm you can connect the server through SSH before transferring the file

```bsh
# Navigate to the directory
cd /mnt/c/Users/test/

# Review the file permissions for test1.zip
ls -l

# Change permissions to read access for the user
chmod 400 test1.zip

# Transfer to remote server (After confirming you can log in via SSH)
scp ./test1.zip user1@stuff:/home/test/codes/
```

Comment: thanks for the response. Upvoted